# Haskell compilation with gcc error

Tags: haskell, gcc, linker

I have been trying to compile Haskell code using ghc (just for playing with Haskell) but get an error during the gcc linking part.

```
ghc --make compileTest.hs 
Linking compileTest ...
/usr/bin/ld: --hash-size=31: unknown option
/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my gcc version:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I don't understand the subtleties of the different flag that gcc accepts and could not find any reference to that error on google. Also, I don't think I can change directly the call to gcc since it is launched by the ghc command for compiling Haskell files.

The verbose version looks like this.

```
:~/haskell_code$ ghc --make compileTest.hs -v
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.4.2, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.4.2
Using binary package database: /usr/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/package.cache
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.2.0.0-7d3c2c69a5e8257a04b2c679c40e2fa7
wired-in package integer-gmp mapped to integer-gmp-0.4.0.0-af3a28fdc4138858e0c7c5ecc2a64f43
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.5.1.0-6e4c9bdc36eeb9121f27ccbbcb62e3f3
wired-in package rts mapped to builtin_rts
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.7.0.0-2bd128e15c2d50997ec26a1eaf8b23bf
wired-in package dph-seq not found.
wired-in package dph-par not found.
Hsc static flags: -static
*** Chasing dependencies:
Chasing modules from: *compileTest.hs
Stable obj: [Main]
Stable BCO: []
Ready for upsweep
  [NONREC
      ModSummary {
         ms_hs_date = Sun Apr 21 23:11:03 IST 2013
         ms_mod = main:Main,
         ms_textual_imps = [import (implicit) Prelude]
         ms_srcimps = []
      }]
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting: 
compile: input file compileTest.hs
Created temporary directory: /tmp/ghc20569_0
*** Checking old interface for main:Main:
[1 of 1] Skipping  Main             ( compileTest.hs, compileTest.o )
Upsweep completely successful.
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting: /tmp/ghc20569_0/ghc20569_0.s
Warning: deleting non-existent /tmp/ghc20569_0/ghc20569_0.s
link: linkables are ...
LinkableM (Sun Apr 21 23:11:17 IST 2013) main:Main
   [DotO compileTest.o]
Linking compileTest ...
*** C Compiler:
'/usr/bin/gcc' '-fno-stack-protector' '-Wl,--hash-size=31' '-Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads' '-c' '/tmp/ghc20569_0/ghc20569_0.c' '-o' '/tmp/ghc20569_0/ghc20569_0.o' '-DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE' '-I/usr/lib/ghc/include'
*** C Compiler:
'/usr/bin/gcc' '-fno-stack-protector' '-Wl,--hash-size=31' '-Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads' '-c' '/tmp/ghc20569_0/ghc20569_0.s' '-o' '/tmp/ghc20569_0/ghc20569_1.o' '-DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE' '-I/usr/lib/ghc/include'
*** Linker:
'/usr/bin/gcc' '-fno-stack-protector' '-Wl,--hash-size=31' '-Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads' '-o' 'compileTest' 'compileTest.o' '-L/usr/lib/ghc/base-4.5.1.0' '-L/usr/lib/ghc/integer-gmp-0.4.0.0' '-L/usr/lib/ghc/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0' '-L/usr/lib/ghc' '/tmp/ghc20569_0/ghc20569_0.o' '/tmp/ghc20569_0/ghc20569_1.o' '-lHSbase-4.5.1.0' '-lHSinteger-gmp-0.4.0.0' '-lgmp' '-lHSghc-prim-0.2.0.0' '-lHSrts' '-lffi' '-lm' '-lrt' '-ldl' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Izh_static_info' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Czh_static_info' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Fzh_static_info' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziPtr_Ptr_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziWord_Wzh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziInt_I8zh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziInt_I16zh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziInt_I32zh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziInt_I64zh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziWord_W8zh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziWord_W16zh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziWord_W32zh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziWord_W64zh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziStable_StablePtr_static_info' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Izh_con_info' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Czh_con_info' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Fzh_con_info' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_con_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziPtr_Ptr_con_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziPtr_FunPtr_con_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziStable_StablePtr_con_info' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_False_closure' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_True_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziPack_unpackCString_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziIOziException_stackOverflow_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziIOziException_heapOverflow_closure' '-u' 'base_ControlziExceptionziBase_nonTermination_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziIOziException_blockedIndefinitelyOnMVar_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziIOziException_blockedIndefinitelyOnSTM_closure' '-u' 'base_ControlziExceptionziBase_nestedAtomically_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziWeak_runFinalizzerBatch_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziTopHandler_flushStdHandles_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziTopHandler_runIO_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziTopHandler_runNonIO_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziConcziIO_ensureIOManagerIsRunning_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziConcziSync_runSparks_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziConcziSignal_runHandlers_closure'
/usr/bin/ld: --hash-size=31: unknown option
/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting: /tmp/ghc20569_0/ghc20569_1.o /tmp/ghc20569_0/ghc20569_0.s /tmp/ghc20569_0/ghc20569_0.o /tmp/ghc20569_0/ghc20569_0.c
*** Deleting temp dirs:
Deleting: /tmp/ghc20569_0
```

Comment: does ghci compileTest.hs work?

Comment: What is your `ld`? Mine (`GNU ld (GNU Binutils; openSUSE 12.3) 2.23.1`) understands `--hash-size=31`. If yours is actually `gold`, I seem to recall that that has problems with the flags passed by GHC. Don't remember how to treat it.

Comment: @DanielFischer I was using gold. After shifting to ld it links without any complaints. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ghc seems to use an option specific to the old version of ld, as mentioned by Daniel Fisher. You can override the choice of ld by putting it first in your path.

First test that you have `ld.bfd` (the old program):

```
$ which ld.bfd
/usr/bin/ld.bfd
```

Then make yourself a directory for local programs. I use ~/bin. If you have not already got a directory like that, put the following in your `.profile` file, and restart all shells (e.g. `bash`).

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Then, add an override for `ld.bfd`.

```
$ cd bin
~/bin$ ln -s `which ld.bfd` ld
~/bin$ ls -l ld
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 15 Oct  1 15:44 ld -> /usr/bin/ld.bfd
```

Does that help?